# Emoji Icon is showing Strange Letters in TextView

Tags: android, emoji

I know this questions already has been asked by some peoples but Still I am getting issue fro last 1 day. I have chat application and My emoji is sent successfully and displaying perfect in Website but In TextView its returning strange characters. I am using this [Library for Emoji in TextView](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3319)

This is Response from Web

```
data
```

:
"{"type":"text","message":"\ud83d\ude29","to":"264","from":"175","group_id":"0","groupFlag":0}"

but My TextView showing this Value

```
ðÿ˜ðÿ˜¡ðÿ˜¡ðÿ˜¡
```

**My ScreenShot is Here **
[image: Chat History]

Please guide me How can I show Emoji in TextView. ? My complete code is

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
    emojiButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emoji_btn);
    submitButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    emojiconEditText = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.emojicon_edit_text);
    textView = (EmojiconTextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this, rootView, emojiconEditText, emojiButton);
    emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
    emojIcon.setKeyboardListener(new EmojIconActions.KeyboardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardOpen() {
            Log.e("Keyboard", "open");
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyboardClose() {
            Log.e("Keyboard", "close");
        }
    });



    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newText = emojiconEditText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(newText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: disable system default emoji. It will use only app emoji not system

Comment: hi @androidXP sorry no luck.. still its not showing emoji except Special Character set

Answer (score 0):

can you try this may be worked:
emojIcon.setUseSystemEmoji(true);

Comment: Thnxx for your reply. but still Its showing strange characters set

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need you need to convert the Html request to string

```
Html.fromHtml((String) YOUR_STRING_HERE).toString()
```

Comment: HI tried sir.. but no luck.. Even I am not able to find out why this showing issue when SDample is doing very fine for this library

Comment: Maybe There's something you are not doing right. If you are completely stuck, post it as issue in sDample github library